# If I delete a row from a table in a database how to rename the primary keys

Tags: mysql

So I want to delete a row from a table e.g

1

2

3

4

5

7

8

How do I rename the tables rows primary keys so they are equal to

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

Comment: You don't. There is no reason to keep your primary keys sequential. The whole point is that you can delete #4 and the rest of the records are unaffected.

Comment: I am doing it for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: That is the worst possible reason. **Do not do this**. This is not how databases work.

Comment: Also it can be more useful, if you reference the deleted row, that you get an error, instead of a completely different row.

Comment: @SidWebber Then you should not use this as primary key

Comment: If you want to change a primary key, it is not actually a primary key.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC;

Comment: This is a very bad idea, note that if other tables are linked to the ID in this table, you would have to update these too or your relationships between the tables disappear.

Comment: @SidWebber use your DB's onupdate/ondelete foreign key magic if you are having a problem with reference non-existent rows... (or do it in your application (but don't as its ugly!))

Comment: Although I fail to see the reason for the downvotes...

Comment: That's right. What you're asking for is possible. But this is almost certainly a case where it's better to step back and ask yourself what you're trying to do. It may not be possible in your case but you can use the PK for ordering and leave the sequential row numbers for the application to calculate.

Answer (score 5):

This question comes frequently but it's a false problem. You don't have to care about id. It's just an identifier. Leave it as it is.

You can add a progressive number programmatically, using your favourite programming language or via sql.

```
select *,@row:=@row+1 as progressive_number
from table, (select @row:=0) as t
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't rename primary keys. Their function is to provide a unique **internal** identifier in your database. Even it has a sequence like 1, 10, 43, 88 .. it doesn't matter as it should have no cosmetic meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the row by its primary key...

```
delete from my_table where id = 4
```

And then decrement all subsequent keys:

```
update my_table set id = id - 1 where id > 4;
```

Assuming all the foreign keys referencing the primary key are set to `on update cascade`, the *internal* referential integrity will be maintained. If you're using the numeric id to build URLs, your URLs are all now broken.

But you absolutely should not do this. This is not how databases work. It is not a case of aesthetics, it is **outright wrong** to do this with your data. This is literally no good reason to do this, and a ton  of reasons not to.